# Current path in Dired or Dired+ to clipboard

Tags: dired

Say we have a Dired buffer open on some directory. How can I send the directory path to the clipboard?

Also, how can I do the same when the Dired cursor is on a specific file, without opening the file first?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Move the cursor to the directory header line (where the directory is shown - e.g., use `M-<`), then hit `w`. That copies the directory name to the kill ring. (`w` copies any file name from Dired, and it works for the directory header too.)

And if you haven't already done so, customize `x-select-enable-clipboard` to non-`nil`, so selection is copied to the clipboard.

---

@Constantine's comment makes a good point. Instead of moving to the directory header line to get the absolute name, you can just use `C-0 w` on any file or directory line. That will put the absolute file name in the clipboard. When you paste it you can just remove the relative file-name part, to get the absolute directory name.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the `C-h k w` in a `dired` buffer says "With a zero prefix arg, use the absolute file name of each marked file.", i.e. "press `C-0 w` to get the absolute path."

Comment: @Constantine: Good point. I updated the answer to mention this.

Comment: @Constantine: you could use "0 w" (it is the same thing as "C-0 w" in a dired buffer)

Comment: In dired mode use "C-0 w". This copy full path (path + file name) to kill ring.

Comment: How does one search this in `Emacs commands?

Comment: @jjk: I don't understand what you're asking. What is "this" that you want to search, and what does "in `Emacs commands" mean?

Comment: @Drew Nevermind, fuzzyfinding `dired-do-copy-filename` and reading what it does answered my question. I was looking for some kind of mnemonic for `C 0 w` in helm `Emacs commands`.

Answer (score 1):

I set `x-select-enable-clipbard` to `t` as suggested but it didn't work. I use this piece of code from here: http://blog.binchen.org/posts/copy-file-name-or-full-path-of-file-in-emacs-dired-buffer-into-system-clipboard.html

```
;; {{ copy the file-name/full-path in dired buffer into clipboard
;; `w` => copy file name
;; `C-u 0 w` => copy full path
(defadvice dired-copy-filename-as-kill (after dired-filename-to-clipboard activate)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (current-kill 0))
    (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max)
                             (cond
                              ((eq system-type 'cygwin) "putclip")
                              ((eq system-type 'darwin) "pbcopy")
                              (t "xsel -ib")
                              )))
  (message "%s => clipboard" (current-kill 0))
  )
```